Bound for the upper level set
If $\int_X exp({a|f_j(x)|})d\mu(x)\le C$ for all $j$ (for some $a>0$) with  $f_1,\dots,f_n$ on the probability space $(X,\mu)$  and $L^2$ norm of $f_j$ is bounded by $\eta^j$ for all $j$, for some $\eta\in(0,1)$, then for all $\delta>0$, there exists $\kappa$ such that  $\mu(\{x|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f_j(x)\ge \delta\})\lesssim e^{-\kappa n}. $
I split the sum from $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{1}^{n}$ into 2 sums: $j=1$ to $j=\ell$ and from $j=\ell+1$ to $n$, then trying to choose $\ell$ latter on. The latter (sum from $\ell+1$ to $n$, we can use the Chevbyshev inequality to bound the upper level set. But the first one, I don't know how to get around with the first sum since $f_j(x), j=1,...,\ell$ maybe dependent so when apply Markov inequality, I cannot interchange the product and integral. Any help would be appreciate.

Is your first inequality quite right? It implies that $f_j=0$ almost surely.

@Wei: Thanks, I meant for some constant $C$, I edited it.

Hello and welcome to Math.SE. Please choose a unique title so that, standing alone, it theoretically reflects your question (I'm not even sure what the question is). You can find more information about this here.
